# No me funciona el validar si hay texto recibido por HTTP en las variables

Tags: php

No sé si lo estoy haciendo bien, pero no me valida si se recibió texto en las variales por petición *HTTP*, mientras si lo hago *$variable = ""* si lo hace

```js
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$password =  $_POST['password'];

if (strlen($email) > 0 && strlen($password) > 0) {
echo "Datos ingresados...";
}
```

La data recibida es:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(12) "...@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump()` a `$_POST` y añade en tu pregunta que obtienes por favor

Comment: @BetaM var_dump($email) > 0 = NULL

Comment: Me refiero a que hagas la impresión de `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: array(2) { ["email"]=> string(12) "...@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Una vez que comprobamos que información llega entonces podemos identificar que la causa de que no se imprima el mensaje dentro del condicional es que al usar el operador && es necesario ambas condiciones evalúen a true, como en la segunda string no es mayor a 0 provoca que el texto no salga por pantalla, aquí debes considerar hacer llegar un valor al password o usar el operador || claro todo dependiendo que conviene mas de acuerdo con lo que necesites